# IndexOutOfRangeException. There is no row at position 0

Tags: vb.net

Trying to update data in a GridView and received an exception error.  Originally, I had **GridView1.EditIndex = -1**, then I read up that the index number should not be a negative so I changed it to **=1** but still it didn't work.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim dt As New DataTable("historyList")

    dt.Columns.Add("TicketID", GetType(Integer))
    dt.Columns.Add("DateCreated", GetType(DateTime))
    dt.Columns.Add("FullName", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("TicketType", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Subject", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Message", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Status", GetType(String))

    For i = 0 To 6
        Dim tableRow = dt.NewRow()
        tableRow("TicketID") = i
        tableRow("DateCreated") = Now()
        tableRow("FullName") = i.ToString()
        tableRow("TicketType") = i.ToString()
        tableRow("Subject") = i.ToString()
        tableRow("Message") = i.ToString()
        tableRow("Status") = i.ToString()
    Next

    Session("dt") = dt

    BindData()

End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewEditEventArgs)
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    BindData()
End Sub
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCancelEditEventArgs)
    GridView1.EditIndex = 1
    BindData()
End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    Dim dt = CType(Session("dt"), DataTable)

    'if your current DataSource be in Session
    Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

    dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("TicketID") = (CType(row.Cells(0).Controls(0), TextBox)).Text
    dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("DateCreated") = (CType(row.Cells(1).Controls(0), TextBox)).Text
    dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("FullName") = (CType(row.Cells(2).Controls(0), TextBox)).Text
    dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("TicketType") = (CType(row.Cells(3).Controls(0), TextBox)).Text
    dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("Subject") = (CType(row.Cells(4).Controls(0), TextBox)).Text
    dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("Message") = (CType(row.Cells(5).Controls(0), TextBox)).Text
    dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("Status") = (CType(row.Cells(6).Controls(0), TextBox)).Text

    Session("dt") = dt
    GridView1.EditIndex = 1
    BindData()

End Sub

Private Sub BindData()

    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

So, here's my aspx codes:

```
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
                    DataKeyNames="TicketID" DataSourceID="historySqlDataSource" ForeColor="#333333" 
                    GridLines="None" Width="828px" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
                    OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TicketID" HeaderText="TicketID" 
                            InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TicketID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateCreated" HeaderText="DateCreated" 
                            SortExpression="DateCreated" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="FullName" HeaderText="FullName" 
                            SortExpression="FullName" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TicketType" HeaderText="TicketType" 
                            SortExpression="TicketType" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Subject" HeaderText="Subject" 
                            SortExpression="Subject" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Message" HeaderText="Message" 
                            SortExpression="Message" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" 
                            SortExpression="Status" />
                    </Columns>
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 3):

Missing a piece in your for loop that add rows

```
For i = 0 To 6
    Dim tableRow = dt.NewRow()
    tableRow("TicketID") = i
    tableRow("DateCreated") = Now()
    tableRow("FullName") = i.ToString()
    tableRow("TicketType") = i.ToString()
    tableRow("Subject") = i.ToString()
    tableRow("Message") = i.ToString()
    tableRow("Status") = i.ToString()
    dt.Rows.Add(tableRow); // <-- this line is required
 Next
```

Comment: @Steve: Add the line, but now it says **Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlLinkButton' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'.**  What am I missing?

Comment: That's probably depend by your GridView definition in the aspx file. Better to post a new question

Comment: @Esther: You have to show your `GridView` aspx markup, then we can tell you how you can access the `TextBox`. In general you have to use `row.FindControl("TextBoxId")` if you use `TemplateFields`. If you are using BoundFields and the text is in the second cell(because the first cell contains the edit-link) you have to use `row.Cells(1).Text`.

Comment: @Steve: Can I just post the .aspx file since it's kind of on same topic?  Just curious.  Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what is the best practice in this scenario. Just thinking that this is a different problem and thus, with a different question, you would be able to acknowledge a different person that will resolve the new problem.

Comment: My code behind for **TicketID** is an integer and I used **Text** in this line `dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("TicketID") = (CType(row.Cells(0).Controls(0), TextBox)).Text`.  Could this have something to do with the error message?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I'm using BoundFields and have changed the `row.Cells(0).Text` to `row.Cells(1).Text`.  Now I get this **Specified arguement was out of the range of valid values.**  Please help.

Comment: No I don't think this is the cause. But you could easily try it commenting out the line. I am not an expert of ASP.NET so I really suggest you to post another question focusing the title on this issue. Otherwise the passersby suppose that your initial problem has already been resolved by my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right, you set the EditIndex after DataBind. Because before that, there is no Index 1.
Try that, please.